# Motion of an object due to movement of ship

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics

I wanted to know how the movement of the object floating near the boat would be like. I've assumed the following scenario:

The floating object is at the location $(x, y)$. The boat starts moving from $(0, 0)$ in the y-direction with a velocity $v_s$. The water is still.

My thinking so far is as follows:

So due to the movement of the boat, there will flow of water let its velocity be $v_w$. Due to which a drag will be applied on the object which will be $C_d\rho v_w^2A/2$

After this, I'm unable to proceed further. Also, I think the object will oscillate with damping but I do not have the idea. So can I get help in how the motion of the object will be ?

Comment: What about the z direction?

Comment: in z there won't be any change

Comment: How is that then? Tides, waves etc..

Comment: basically the motion of boat (ship) causes distrubance in water which will cause change in position of the object. I want to predict this position in x-y plane.

Comment: A wave is generated (in the x-y plane) due to the flow of water touching the surface of the boat, as well as some water near by due to the viscosity of the water. The energy associated with this flow would propagate somewhat in standing water. Then in turn that energy would be imparted on your object by viscous forces or drag. The object has its equation of motion defined by the loading that results from the viscous loading of the water in motion. I just want to try to lay out the fundamentals that I picture, is this also what you invision?